# Should I be alarmed by this NO JOIN PREDICATE warning?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan, warning

I'm troubleshooting the bits and pieces of a poorly-performing stored procedure. This section of the procedure is throwing a NO JOIN PREDICATE warning

```
select
    method = 
        case methoddescription 
            when 'blah' then 'Ethylene Oxide'
            when NULL then 'N/A'
            else methoddescription
        end,
    testmethod = 
        case methoddescription 
            when 'blah' then 'Biological Indicators'
            when NULL then 'N/A'
            else 'Dosimeter Reports'
        end,
    result = 
        case when l.res is null or l.res <> 1 then 'Failed'
        else 'Passed'
        end,
    datecomplete = COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10), NULL, 101),'N/A')
from db2.dbo.view ls
    join db1.dbo.table l
        on ls.id = l.id
    where item = '19003'
        and l.id = '732820'
```

The view (`[ls]`) calls a remote server (the remote query %41 on the right of the plan).

Here is an image of the plan:

[image: plan]

I only ask this question because of [this blog post](http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/15/no-join-predicate/) and I want to make sure this won't come back to bite me later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because we know that `l.id = '732820'` and `ls.id = l.id` then SQL Server derives that `ls.id = '732820'`

i.e.

```
FROM   db2.dbo.VIEW ls
       JOIN db1.dbo.table l
         ON ls.id = l.id
WHERE  l.id = '732820'
```

is the same as

```
  ( /*...*/ FROM   db2.dbo.VIEW ls WHERE id = '732820'  )
   CROSS JOIN 
  ( /*...*/  FROM   db1.dbo.table l WHERE id = '732820'  )
```

This rewrite is [not bad for performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/implied-predicates-and-query-hints) .

> This derivation is a good thing.  It allows SQL Server to filter out
> rows ... earlier than would otherwise be possible.